# Touro USB3 drive stopped working in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, usb-3

I have a Hitachi Touro 1TB USB 3.0 drive I use to take films from my desktop PC (Windows 7 64 bit) so I can watch them on my BluRay player or my laptop (Surface Pro 3, Windows 8 64 bit).

Suddenly the USB3 drive has stopped working with the windows 7 machine. I plug it in, I get the USB connected sound but the device does not show in either explorer or in Disk Management. It does show under "drives" in Device manager but only as "Disk Drive", not as the name or model of the drive.

The drive works fine when plugged into my Surface or BlurRay player but not the Win7 machine. This is bad as the Win7 machine is my DVD ripper and where I maintain my media library.

What I have tried:

- Plugging it into non USB3 ports - same result, no drive shows.
- Uninstalling the drive in Device manager to prompt re-install of
  driver oon plug in - I tried this but the driver install process that kicks off when I plug the drive back in fails every time (no idea why this is).
- Looking at Disk Management - Drive does not show in disk management. Maybe due to the point above?

Can anyone help me? I cant seem to find anything to help me out. Could there be a registry entry I have to amend?

thanks,

Ben

Comment: Disconnect the drive, run [USB Oblivion](http://www.cherubicsoft.com/en/projects/usboblivion) with "Do real clean" checked, reboot, reconnect drive and see if driver installation succeeds this time.

Comment: Hi, I ran USB Oblivion and it triggered a driver reinstall for "USB Mass Storage Device" which completed but the second driver "HitachiG ST USB Device" took ages and then failed. I dont know why it's failing. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you test the drive on a machine it has *not* been plugged into so far, so that the driver install is initiated for the first time? Also, on your Win7 PC try creating a new user account and see if things work differently there.

Comment: I got to the bottom of things. I was accessing the drive via a USB extension lead that didnt seem to want to work with the drive either as USB2 or 3. As soon as I took it out of the extension lead and used the port round the back it was fine. Massive thanks for your help though.

Comment: I did nothing but you're welcome anyway. :) Good to know you solved your problem. Please add it as answer below (which you can self-accept after 2 days), or else this question will never be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out that the problem was that the drive was not liking being attached to the USB3 port (or any other port) via an extension lead. Once I plugged the drive in directly and allocated a drive letter in Disk Management things were fine.

Thanks to Karan for the help though!